# Jquery: Object returns value '[object Object]'

Tags: jquery, append

irst at all. Script is here:

```
$(function () {
    var type = 'REP';
    var id = '_r_2059281920';

    $(".math").click(function () {
        function GhostItem(type, owner, index, id, num) {
            this.gstType = type;
            this.gstThumb = "<div class='gst-label gst-pic-01'></div>";
            this.gstOwner = owner;
            this.gstIndex = index;
            this.gstId = id;
            this.gstNum = num;
        }

        GhostItem.prototype.toHTML = function () {
            var out = ""
            out = "<div class='item-mode' >" +
                "<div class='gst-fld gst-label " + this.gstType + "' ></div>" + this.gstThumb +
                "<div class='gst-label gst-owner'><h6>" + this.gstOwner + " </h6><h5>" + this.gstIndex + "</h5></div>" +
                "<div class='gst-label gst-cls '></div>" + this.gstNum + "</div>";
            return out;
        }

        var ghost_item = new GhostItem(type, $(type + id + " h4"), $(type + id + " h5"), '201034545323_a1243098382', '9934595023122');

        GhostItem.prototype.setOwner = function () {
            $(this.gstThumb).append($("#cntInfo_owner" + id));
        }

        ghost_item.setOwner();

        $(".num").append(ghost_item.gstOwner, ghost_item.gstIndex);
        $(".num2").append(ghost_item.toHTML());
    });
});
```

and html:

```
<div class="cntInfo" id="cntInfo_r_2059281920">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="cntInfo_owner_r_2059281920" style="float: left; margin: 5px;">
            <img width="30" height="30" src="http://gyg.altuxa.com/files/2009/06/michael_jackson.jpg?file=2009/06/michael_jackson.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="cntInfowide wrap lfloat" id="REP_r_2059281920">
            <div class="cntIB cntTitle rbor01 lfloat" id="REP_r_2059281920">
                <div class="cInfo_p_headline p_h_4_headline">
                    <h4>MichaelJacksonIsNotDead</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="cInfo_p_headline p_h_5_headline">
                    <h5>The New Yorkers</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- others object -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 <h2>Javascript Object 'this' Testing</h2>

<button class="math">Click here</button>
<div class="num">
    <p>num</p>
</div>
<div class="num2">
    <p>num 2</p>
</div>
```

cntInfo html object came from ajax. I want to **copy** a part of cntInfo into num2! Not move! but result is [object Object] and GhostItem.prototype.setOwner function doesn't work. append($("#cntInfo_owner" + id)) is no good. Object Gone away.

How can I solve it?

Comment: You're calling the constructor with 6 arguments, but it only has 5 parameter variables. Could that be the problem?

Comment: It's ok. It doesn't matter. I fixed that. Thanks Barmar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had called the constructor with 6 arguments, but it only has 5 parameter variables.
Thanks Barmar